# Check to see if exists in the database

Tags: php

**Hello

I own a short url website where i want users to be able to change their short url tag (mydomain.com/TAG) to anything if it's avaliable in the database. Check in the HTML it's called "Current Short url" The problem i am facing is that when i press the "submit" button it just saves the newshort url even if it already exists in the database or not.

How can i make it check and put up "setError(t("Short Url Already Taken"));" if it exists in the database?

In functions.php there is a function to allow a certain domain only if you wish. Can this be made into a function to check for the Shorturl ? **

**FUNCTIONS.php**

```
<?php

    /* allow specific url */
    function denyotherdomainsthan($url)
    {
        $strAllow = 'mydomain.com'; 
        $strBase  = getBaseUrl($url);
        if(strpos($url, $strAllow) === false)
        {
            return true;
        }
                
    }
?>
```

**INDEX.PHP**

```
<?php


// make sure this user owns the short url
$urlId    = (int) $_REQUEST['id'];
$shortUrl = ShortUrl::loadById($urlId);
if ($shortUrl->userId != $user->id)
{
    redirect(WEB_ROOT);
}

// stop users from un-spamming their urls
if ($shortUrl->status == 'spam')
{
    redirect(WEB_ROOT);
}

//setup defaults
$shortUrlStatusList = array('active', 'expired', 'disabled');
$original_url       = $shortUrl->fullUrl;
$short_url          = $shortUrl->fullshortUrl;
$privatestats       = $shortUrl->privatestats;
$shortUrlFolder     = $shortUrl->shortUrlFolder;
$folderListing      = $db->getRows("SELECT id, folder_name FROM shorturl_folder WHERE user_id = " . $Auth->id . " ORDER BY folder_name");

/* setup page */
define("PAGE_NAME", t("url_edit_page_name", "Edit Url"));
define("PAGE_DESCRIPTION", t("url_edit_meta_description", "Edit Url"));
define("PAGE_KEYWORDS", t("url_edit_meta_keywords", "details, account, short, url, user"));
define("SITE_SELECTED_PAGE", "account_home");

/* update user */
if ((int) $_REQUEST['submitme'])
{
    // validation
    $original_url = trim($_REQUEST['original_url']);
    $original_url = strip_tags($original_url);
    $original_url = str_replace("\n", "", $original_url);
    $original_url = str_replace("\r", "", $original_url);
    $short_url    = trim($_REQUEST['short_url']);
    $short_url = strip_tags($short_url);
    $short_url = str_replace("\n", "", $short_url);
    $short_url = str_replace("\r", "", $short_url);
    $status       = trim($_REQUEST['status']);
    $privatestats = (int)$_REQUEST['privatestats'];


    $shortUrlFolder = null;
    if ((int) $_REQUEST['shortUrlFolder'])
    {
        $shortUrlFolder = $_REQUEST['shortUrlFolder'];
    }

    else
    {
        if (!isValidUrl($original_url))
        {
            setError(t("error_with_urls", "There was an error with the url you supplied, please check and try again."));
        }
        /* check that they are not using the site url to restrict infinate loops */
        elseif (substr(strtolower($original_url), 0, strlen(WEB_ROOT)) == strtolower(WEB_ROOT))
        {
            setError(t("can_not_create_url_on_this_site"));
        }
        
    }
   
$status = 'active';

    // update the account
    if (!isErrors())
    {
        $db = Database::getDatabase(true);
        $rs = $db->query('UPDATE shorturl SET shortUrl = :shortUrl, originalUrl = :originalUrl, status = :status, expiryDate=null, shortUrlFolder=:shortUrlFolder, privatestats=:privatestats WHERE id = :id', array('originalUrl'    => $original_url, 'shortUrl'    => $short_url, 'status'         => $status, 'shortUrlFolder' => $shortUrlFolder, 'privatestats' => $privatestats, 'id'             => $urlId));
        if ($rs)
        {
            setSuccess(t("url_edit_updated_success_message", "Url details successfully updated, <a href='[[[YOUR_URLS_LINK]]]'>click here</a> to go to your urls.", array('YOUR_URLS_LINK' => WEB_ROOT . '/account_home.' . SITE_CONFIG_PAGE_EXTENSION)));
        }
        else
        {
            setError(t("problem_updating_the_url_try_again_later", "There was a problem updating the url, please try again later"));
        }
    }
}


require_once('_header.php');
?>

<div class="span9 page_sidebar accountDetails">

    <?php
    if (isSuccess())
    {
        echo outputSuccess();
    }
    elseif (isErrors())
    {
        echo outputErrors();
    }
    ?>

    <div class="well">
        <h3><?php echo t("url_details", "Url Details"); ?>: <font color="green">domain.COM/<?php echo $shortUrl->shortUrlPart; ?></font></h3>
        <hr/>
        <form method="post" action=" " onSubmit="window.location.reload()" class="form">
            <div>
            
                <label for="original_url">
                    <?php echo "<b>Current Destination</b>"; ?>
                </label>
                <textarea id="original_url" name="original_url" tabindex="1"><?php echo safeOutputToScreen($original_url); ?></textarea>
                <div class="third">
                
                <label for="short_url">
                <?php echo "<b>Current Short url</b>"; ?>
                </label>
                <textarea id="short_url" name="short_url" tabindex="1"><?php echo safeOutputToScreen($short_url); ?></textarea>
                <div class="third">

            <div class="buttonWrapper">
                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" tabindex="99"><?php echo t("update_url", "update url"); ?></button>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>

            <input type="hidden" value="1" name="submitme"/>
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $urlId; ?>" name="id"/>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you verified `$shortUrl->shortUrl` and `$short_url` are indeed the same? As for the need to press the button twice, you have to redirect after saving so that it retrieves the updated values from the database. Without the redirect, you're just showing the original values from before the update.

Comment: FYI: Your code is wide open to SQL Injection - always use a prepared statement rather than embedding user supplied data directly in the sql command

Comment: `if ($rs == $short_url){` - this is bogus!  `$rs` is most likely a boolean and `$short_url` is a string. You need to `fetch` the result from the query

Answer (score 0):

To mitigate the SQL Injection threat use a [prepared statement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) - the below is with `mysqli` but this is equally possible with PDO.

Once the query has been run you need to fetch the result from the query because otherwise you are trying to compare things of different types ( booleans to strings )

```
<?php   
    if( !isErrors() ) {
    
        #$db = Database::getDatabase( true );   // assume this is mysqli???
        
        mysqli_report( MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT );
        $db=new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );        
        
        $url=trim( $_REQUEST['short_url'] );
        

        
        $sql='select `shorturl` from `shorturl` where `shorturl` = ?';
        $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->bind_param( 's', $url );
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result( $shorturl );
        $stmt->fetch();
        
        if( $shorturl==$url ) setError("Short URL already exists");
    }
?>
```